# Remove Blank Entries in List

Tags: haskell

Let's say that I declare a variable in GHCI

```
let a = ["hello","goodbye","","sup","bye","hi","cat","dog"]
```

And I want to go about removing that pesky "" from the list.  From my understanding, I should be able to use dropWhile to do so, like this

```
dropWhile null a
```

But this doesn't remove the pesky "".  Why is this?  How can I fix this issue?

Ah, now I understand.  I completely misunderstood how dropWhile works.  So then to make this question a little different - how do I remove blank entries in a list?

Answer (score 10):

[`dropWhile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:dropWhile) drops elements while given predicate is `True`. `null "hello"` is `False`, so, it should'n drop anything.

You are probably looking for a [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter):

```
Prelude> filter (not . null) ["hello","goodbye","","sup","bye","hi","cat","dog"]
["hello","goodbye","sup","bye","hi","cat","dog"]
```